# Intermittent empty document response afyter PHP 7.4 upgrade with no errors logged or displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.4

After upgrade from PHP 7.0 to 7.4 I noticed an intermittent issue on my Wordpress site. When I open a page initially the server will return an empty response. Reloading the browser will cause the page to load correctly without any issues. The site will continue to operate normally, but if I wait a period of time (not sure how long exactly ~30+ min) the issue will reappear. The page always loads correctly after refreshing and no errors appear in the WP DEBUG log, PHP error log, Apache2 log, Syslog or the MySQL log. I've tried to disable plugins and change themes to see if that resolves the issue, but since the issue takes a long time to reoccur, that makes it challenging to debug. Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this or where to look? My only theory is that some sort of cache or data store is empty on first load and populated after first load, but I have no idea what that could be. Any input would be helpful!

I enabled WP debugging and checked the WP DEBUG log, PHP error log, Apache2 log, Syslog and the MySQL log. No errors were present. I also tried changing themes and deactivating plugins to try to narrow down the issue, but I suspect I was getting false results because I may not have waited long enough for the issue to occur. The site loaded fine when the theme was changed and the plugins were deactivated but I'm not sure that I waited long enough because my final test was setting everything back to the initial state and that seemed to work as well.